# Alternate figure captions in appendix

Tags: sectioning, captions, appendices

In a paper with figures generated from simulations, I would like to specify the parameters used to run the simulations in an appendix section. How do I implement a command within each figure environment that will add a subsection to a section in the appendix which specifies these details for each figure. I imagine something like this:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.png}
   \caption{Description of figure 1...}
   \label{fig:fig1}
   \altcaption{Nitty-gritty details of figure \ref{fig:fig1}...}
\end{figure}

... some body text ...

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2.png}
   \caption{Description of figure 2...}
   \label{fig:fig2}
   \altcaption{Nitty-gritty details of figure \ref{fig:fig2}... Maybe even contains a reference to \ref{fig:fig1}}
\end{figure}

... rest of body text...

\appendix

\section{Appendix 1}

... appendix 1 text ...

\section{Figure details}

\altcaptionlist
```

which would output an appendix section titled "Figure details" whose subsections are titled "Figure 1 details" and "Figure 2 details" and whose contents would include "Nitty-gritty details of figure 1" and "Nitty-gritty details of figure 2... Maybe even contains a reference to figure 1", respectively.

An ideal implementation would have the above form, but anything that produces this sort of result without manual organization of the appendix subsections would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the argument of `\altcaption` meant to be a descriptive legend? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico , yes. `\altcaption` is meant to be a descriptive legend in that it gives more information about the plot included that would be inconveniently lengthy to include in the caption. In my case, it would be a space to specify parameters used in a simulation or elaborate upon details of the particular simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `\altcaption` be synonymous to a macro that adds an item to a list, while `\altcaptionlist` processes this list of stored items. Using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s list processing capabilities, this is fairly straight forward.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\altcaption}{}{\listgadd{\altcaplist}}% Store \altcaption in list \altcaplist
\NewDocumentCommand{\altcaptionlist}{}{%
  % Process \altcaplist
  \begin{itemize}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\do}{ m }{\item ##1}% Each item is an \item
    \dolistloop{\altcaplist}%
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Description of first figure}
  \label{fig:fig1}
  \altcaption{Nitty-gritty details of Figure~\ref{fig:fig1}\ldots}
\end{figure}

\ldots some body text\ldots

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Description of second figure}
  \label{fig:fig2}
  \altcaption{Nitty-gritty details of Figure~\ref{fig:fig2}\ldots Maybe even contains a reference to Figure~\ref{fig:fig1}}
\end{figure}

\ldots rest of body text\ldots

\appendix

\section{Appendix 1}

\ldots Appendix text\ldots

\section{Figure details}

\altcaptionlist

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution, but I would ideally like the list of alternate captions to be a series of subsections instead of a bullet list. Is this possible?

Comment: @EmmyB: Sure. I assume you don't want these `\subsection`s to go into the ToC, right?

Comment: I would prefer that they are not listed in the ToC. However, for my personal purposes, it is not relevant because this will be part of a letter-style paper. Thanks!

Comment: @EmmyB: If you want unnumbered `\subsection`s, you can use [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/sWnWtSQp). If you want numbered `\subsection`s, use [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/pMxCnpfz).

Comment: Thank you so much!